# SD card not mounting

Tags: windows, mac, sd-card

A friend got his SD card wiped by his phone (galaxy S5). 
I'm trying to recover his data for him. I need to mount the SD card either on windows or Mac Yosemite. Hope you guys can help me :)

Android:
Says SD card is empty and needs to be formatted. Clicked format and it formats, checks for errors, completed. Android keeps saying it needs to be formatted.

Windows:
Sometimes it randomly shows in explorer, but can't click it and it won't load. 
It shows up in device manager but it never shows up in disk management.

Mac:
can't get it to show in disk manager..

What do I do next?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty SD Card to me. See: http://superuser.com/questions/389221/what-are-my-best-options-to-recover-data-from-a-faulty-sd-micro-card-used-in-an?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can try a recovery software that scans the media sector by sector (like Get Data Back for FAT). Such a software does not require a valid file system and if the card is still readable (even if it has bad sectors) it will get you back some files.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that every time the phone formats it, it's wiping all the data from it.

Did a quick search though, and this may work for you. Be aware that it entirely command line:

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec
```

Comment: A quick format will not wipe the entire card. Bad news is, on FAT chances of recovering fragmented files are low.